# The difference between 'few weeks' vs 'a few weeks'

Tags: word-usage

I've been trying to find out the difference between 'few weeks' and ''a few weeks'. And here's a sentence written in my textbook.

> A memorable incident happend during my first **few weeks**.

it is more like putting emphasis on how soon it happened.

> A memorable incident happened during my first **a few weeks**.

But there's nothing emphasizing how soon the incident happened.

Am I right

Comment: I hope it's clear that *my first a few weeks* is totally ungrammatical.

Comment: I got to know I was wrong to write that sentence due to the good answer. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case "my first" acts like a definitive article, *clearly specifying* a unique time frame. Using an additional indefinitive one would not work - a grammatical contradiction, you could say.

If you want to put *more* emphasis on the early time, you need to rewrite the sentence, e.g.:

> A memorable incident happened during my *very* first few weeks. *or*
>   A memorable incident happened *just* during my first few weeks. 
>   (Or rewrite entirely.)

Comment: I wouldn't use "just during". I would say "in" or "less than three weeks after I started". The incident did not last throughout the first few weeks, and we don't need to emphasize that it didn't happen again after that; but to say "just during" implies both of those.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, terms like *few hours* and *few weeks* refer to approximate blocks of time. They are often preceded by the indefinite article:

> We can have your car fixed in ***a few hours***.
>   Emily has been working on her paper for ***a few days***.
>   That new movie is coming out in ***a few days***. I can't wait!

but other words can be used in place of the article; for example:

> ***My first few weeks*** on the job were nervewracking.
>   It has been very cold here for ***the past few days***.
>   He always seems to perform well in ***the last few minutes*** of a big game.

It is possible to use "few" without such qualifiers, but the meaning is not the same:

> Few days in my life were as miserable as that one.

In that case, "few days" is not a contiguous block of time, but refers to a small number of specific days. Similarly:

> Few winters have been as cold as this one.

likely refers to non-consecutive winters (such as, say, the winters of 1993, 1979, and 1899), whereas:

> It has been cold for **a** few winters now.

limits the scope of the discussion to the recent past.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are instances where you can have the phrase "a few weeks" start a sentence or place it in the medial or final position of a sentence. For example, it is grammatically correct to say

> "A few weeks ago, I received a cheque."

Or

> "I received a cheque a few weeks ago"

or

> "I saw him a few weeks ago and he walked past me".

The introduction of the article **a** means the phrase *few weeks* is **definite and specific** and we can also have the article removed in the sentence. It would still make sense grammatically and lexically. We can also have phrases like

> "Some few weeks ago...", "Many weeks ago..."

depending on context of use but make sure you don't violate grammatical and lexical rules when constructing these sentences.